# Building HMM from the data

Tags: algorithm, uigesturerecognizer, kinect, gesture, hidden-markov-models

I have a problem with `Hidden Markov Models`. I'm writing an app in `C#` on `Kinect` for gesture recognition (simple gestures as swipes, waves, circles etc.). I wrote a system for gesture recording, after that I created a feature extractor that counts velocities between points and I also count orientations (the angle between pairs of points) - I think it's a simple vector quantization method, because I created a codebook with codewords 1-18. Codewords are angles' intervals every 20 degrees (e.g. angle 12dg is a codeword-1, 45dg = codeword-3 etc.).

Now I guess I need to create a `HMM` and use some `Forward-Backward` algorithm for learning. Then some `Bayes` classification method and finish.

My questions:

1. Am I wrong in my steps?
2. How to create a HMM? Could anyone describe how it should look like programatically?
3. How to perform LIVE gesture matching for tests?

Comment: Instead of giving minus, maybe point me where Im wrong or what's bad in my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of some of the tutorials/software I am going to list.

1. Your steps seems fine. They are very similar, for example, to the method used by [Lee and Kim](http://herin.kaist.ac.kr/Publication/PS/hklee_PAMI_i09611.pdf) (minus the threshold models part).
2. Perhaps you can follow [this guide on HMMs in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541428/Sequence-Classifiers-in-Csharp-Part-I-Hidden-Marko). It was written by me, and have some examples on how to perform the gesture recognition. However, the guide creates continuous-density HMMs rather than discrete HMMs. Your vector quantization makes your features discrete, so I guess you would be more interested in using discrete-density HMMs. The only changes you have to do to make it work with discrete models is to remove the generic arguments in the model creation/learning.
3. To perform live gestures, you can either use some kind of specific marker to signal the starting and ending of a gesture, or you can use a technique similar to Lee and Kim's threshold models. The framework described in the aforementioned guide has support for those.

I have worked on a similar project using the same technology and I can say HMMs work just fine for the task.